# I have a problem after I want to install Waterfox when I use apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I used these commands for install:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/hawkeye116477:/waterfox/xUbuntu_Next/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:hawkeye116477:waterfox.list"

wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:hawkeye116477:waterfox/xUbuntu_Next/Release.key -O Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key 

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install waterfox
```

This is the error I get:

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/hawkeye116477:/waterfox/xUbuntu_Next  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5E62D791625A271E

E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/hawkeye116477:/waterfox/xUbuntu_Next  InRelease' is not signed.
```

Answer (score -1):

found a simple solution .

Go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d

There you can find two files your parrot.list and the other hawkeye file.

Open a terminal in that folder and enter "sudo rm *file name* ".

Will work like a charm.

You can later try installing waterfox again.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.